# Build is succeeded but output is not copied to bin folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

I created an MVC application using asp.net-core in visual studio 2015. when i try to build the application project, it is showing build succeeded with no errors, but the "application.exe" is not available in bin folder.

I tried to resolve the issue by following ways, but none worked for me,

1. I verified output path of the project file and it is pointing to "./bin".
2. I removed some of the required dlls used by the application and try to build. Instead of showing error, build output shows "build succeeded".
3. I repaired all previewing tools required for asp.net core and visual studio 2015.
4. I used dotnet.exe to build the project which showed me

//command to build the project

```
dotnet.exe build "D:\myWebUI\src\WebUI" --configuration Debug --no-dependencies --no-incremental
```

//error thrown

> D:\myWebUI\src\WebUI(41,64): error NU1001: The dependency System.Text.
>   Encodings.Web >= 4.0.0 could not be resolved.
>
> D:\myWebUI\src\WebUI: error NU1001: The dependency NuGet.Versioning >=
>   3.5.0-beta2-1484 could not be resolved.

Someone please help me to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in your project.json ?

Comment: This is my project.json https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_qXJd8KojUc1hIVE9iWnhsQk0/view?usp=sharing